# Jsch Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Lorg.ietf.jgss.Oid

Tags: java, android, jsch

For some reason, after upgrading to Lollipop ( 5.0.2 ) jsch stopped working . I get this error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
    "Lorg.ietf.jgss.Oid" on path: DexPathList[[zip file"/data/app
    /com.**-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories= [/vendor/lib, 
    /system/lib]] 
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) 
 ... 14 more
 Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ietf.jgss.Oid 
 at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 
 at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504) 
 ... 15 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
 boot class loader; no stack available
```

This is my code.

```
try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session = jsch.getSession(userName, remoteHost, port);
    session.setPassword(userPassword);

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.connect();

    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");          
    channel.connect();
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    session.disconnect();
}
```

I detected that the problem occurs when the property is added "**StrictHostKeyChecking**", only then the program closes when execute "**session.connect()**".

If I omit this property, the program does not fail, but cannot connect.

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. The problem is caused by tha the Lorg.ietf.jgss.Oid is not found which is used with GSS-API. I found that this can be avoided with preferring the password authentication:

```
try {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session = jsch.getSession(userName, remoteHost, port);
    session.setPassword(userPassword);

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                "password"); //add this line to your code

    session.connect();

    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");          
    channel.connect();
    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    session.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: The problem for me is that my server actually requires this GSS-API authentication method,  so this isn't really a solution for me. Nor a work-around :-(